# Want to use <pre> without and css which have defined in css file

Tags: html, css

I am using `bootstreap v3.2` Here I am trying to show fetched result of db to page using `<pre></pre>`
My problem is that it is showing content in bootstreap defined `<pre></pre>`. Only for this tag I dont want to include css for `<pre>` tag.
How to achive this.

On examin pre css is showing

```
pre {
    display: block;
    padding: 9.5px;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    word-break: break-all;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xrcwrn/tk57o42x/1/)**

Comment: No css applied in your fiddle. What do you wnat exactly?

Comment: Pls see question I dont want to use APPLIED CSS ON PRE

Comment: How are you using bootstrap. From CDN or you've downloaded the file?

Comment: That you can add in the `bootstrap.css` to the `pre` some class like `pre.bootstrap{...}` and the styles will be only applied when you use `pre` with that class like `<pre class="bootstrap"></pre>`.

Comment: It is defined as above in `bootstrap.min.css`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find in your `bootstrap.min.js`:

```
pre {
     display: block;
     padding: 9.5px;
     margin: 0 0 10px;
     font-size: 13px;
     line-height: 1.42857143;
     color: #333;
     word-break: break-all;
     word-wrap: break-word;
     background-color: #f5f5f5;
     border: 1px solid #ccc;
     border-radius: 4px;
}
```

And change it to

```
pre.bootstrap { /* or some other class name */
     display: block;
     padding: 9.5px;
     margin: 0 0 10px;
     font-size: 13px;
     line-height: 1.42857143;
     color: #333;
     word-break: break-all;
     word-wrap: break-word;
     background-color: #f5f5f5;
     border: 1px solid #ccc;
     border-radius: 4px;
}
```

And then your `pre` will have default styles. But if you want to use `bootstraps` styles, then put that class to the element like `<pre class="bootstrap"></pre>`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b5L0fv8p/)

Comment: it is fething from in my local host `bootstreap/css/less/code.less` . I am unable to find this file in location

Comment: In `code.less` on line 40 - [file on github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/code.less)

Comment: Problem is in my `bootstreap/css` folder there is no `code.less` fine. In folder I have `bootstrap-theme.css`,`bootstrap-theme.css.map`,`bootstrap-theme.min.css`, `bootstrap.css`,`bootstrap.css.map`,'bootstrap.min.css'